# Can't get div to disappear on resizing

Tags: css, html, resize

I'm trying to get a div to disappear using

```css
@media all and (max-width:1000px) {
  #triangle{ display: none; }
}
```

but it's not working for me for some reason. This is the CSS of the div:

```css
#triangle {
 width: 0;
 height: 0; 
 position:absolute;
 top:110px;
 right:250px;
 border-bottom: 100px solid #d8e2ff; 
 border-left: 100px solid transparent; 
 border-top-right-radius: 0%;
 display:inline-block; 
}
```

Here is the website : http://www.ciaransmith.ie/aboutme.php. The div is the triangle of the speech bubble

Any ideas?

Also, my contact page is displaying wonky sometimes, and other times it displays fine, why is this happening?

Comment: where's the triangle - I can't see it

Comment: The triangle is on the about me page

Comment: try to use `!important` to **display:none** like this: `display:none !important;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
@media all and (max-width:1000px) {
  #triangle{ 
    display: none !important; 
  }
}
```

Please place the code in the file itself not in CSS file

Answer (score 0):

I could only find this:

```
@media all and (max-width:1000px) {
  #whiteback { display: none; }
}
```

Which targets the wrong ID. Perhaps I missed the correct css but either way style isnt being aplied so the *current* issue is either the ID, or the media syntax

Comment: Yep beat me the OP doesn't have that declaration

Answer (score -2):

`display: inline-block;` isn't wrapped in a media query. Add this:

```
@media all and (min-width: 1001px) {
    #triangle {
        display: inline-block;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why wouldn't it? He is changing the `display` attribute in the `max-width` media query but he is setting a default value outside a media query. Remove the `display: inline-block;` from the base `#triangle` selector and add it in a `min-width` media query. It would work the same as adding `display: none !important;`